# Command for \longhookrightarrow

Tags: symbols, arrows

The usual `\rightarrow` has its long version `\longrightarrow`, exactly as `\mapsto` has its long version `\longmapsto`. I was wondering if there exists a basic command for a long `\hookrightarrow`as well. The stupid try `\longhookrightarrrow` sadly doesn't work.

Comment: A separate question: On my machine the math-mode of the question is not rendered. Did I make some basic formatting mistakes?

Comment: See [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/5764)

Comment: The table 166, Werner mentioned, refers to "Comprehensive LaTeX symbols"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[new]{old-arrows}
\begin{document}
$x\hookrightarrow y$
$x\longhookrightarrow y$

$x\varhookrightarrow y$
$x\varlonghookrightarrow y$
\end{document}
```

How to find these glyphs: Open [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and search for `hook` ...

Answer (score 14):

I use `\lhook\joinrel\xrightarrow` to produce flexible arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ A \lhook\joinrel\xrightarrow{f\circ g} B \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It solves the problem, but I decided to accept the other answer for its simplicity.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason: produces a short hookrightarrow...

Comment: The length depends on what you insert above it.

Answer (score 11):

No need for external packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\hooklongrightarrow}{\lhook\joinrel\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\hooklongleftarrow}{\longleftarrow\joinrel\rhook}

\begin{document}

$A\hooklongrightarrow B$

$A\hooklongleftarrow B$

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\hookrightarrow` is `\lhook\joinrel\rightarrow`, so it's very easy to complement it.

[image]

A comment. Beginners tend to overuse long arrows; stick with the short version: it's as clear and takes less space.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\hooklongrightarrow{\mathrel{\lhook\mkern -3.5mu\relbar\mkern -4.5mu → }}
\begin{document}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\[ \begin{array}{@{\vrule width 0.1pt}l@{\vrule width 0.1pt}}
  \hooklongrightarrow\\
   ―――→
  \end{array}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]